# Twitter4j integration through Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, twitter4j

I am trying to integrate Twitter4j library into Android project through Android Studio. Though there are enough materials for integration through Eclipse, there are no materials for integration through Android Studio.

How to do the integration?

Answer (score 24):

Just add `compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.2'` to your `/app/build.gradle` dependencies. It should look like:

```
repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.2'
}
```

Comment: These days, you might want to replace the `compile` configuration with an `implementation` one according to [gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html#changes_6.0). This means you would, for example, replace it with `implementation 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.7'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded the zip file from their site.

1. Extract the files.
2. Get/copy the core jar file. 
   As of my version I got it at 
   **twitter4j-4.0.4 > lib > twitter4j-core-4.0.4.jar**
3. Go to Android Studio and under the tab of project find the libs folder
   **YourProjectname>app>libs**.
4. Paste the jar here, right click on on the jar and choose add as library.

Hope this helps